# Stone-Weierstrass on a sequentially compact space

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

I am unable to prove the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem on a compact metric space via its sequential compactness. If that were possible, one could probably prove the Theorem on a sequentially compact Hausdorff space. I can find neither a proof nor a counterexample for this. So, my question is:

Does the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem hold on a sequentially compact Hausdorff space?